# What libraries are available for interacting with Wikipedia, Wikidata, or MediaWiki in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mediawiki, wikimedia, wikidata

What libraries are available for interacting with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About), [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Introduction), or other [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:What_is_MediaWiki%3F) servers in the [Ruby programming language](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/)?

I can search [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) for recently updated repositories with this query:

[`(mediawiki OR wikipedia OR wikimedia OR wikidata) language:ruby pushed:>2019-01-01`](https://github.com/search?q=%28mediawiki+OR+wikipedia+OR+wikimedia+OR+wikidata%29+language%3Aruby+pushed%3A%3E2019-01-01+&type=repositories)

However, I'd appreciate a description of major libraries.

Answer (score 0):

### MediaWiki API clients

- [MediaWiktory](https://github.com/molybdenum-99/mediawiktory), a thin wrapper around all MediaWiki API features
- [MediaWiki API](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-ruby-api) (Official)
- [MediaWiki::Butt](https://github.com/ftb-gamepedia/mediawiki-butt-ruby)

### MediaWiki Parsers

- [Wikitext parser](https://github.com/wikiscript/wikiscript) Features: Fetch wikitext source for an [article by name](https://github.com/wikiscript/wikiscript/tree/master/wikiscript). [Parse infoboxes](https://github.com/wikiscript/wikiscript/blob/master/countries/parse_infobox.rb).
- [Infoboxer](https://github.com/molybdenum-99/infoboxer), a MediaWiki client and parser, targeting information extraction
- [WikiCloth](https://github.com/nricciar/wikicloth), MediaWiki Parser and converter to HTML

### Utilities

- [MediawikiEditorTool](https://github.com/afukumoto/mediawiki-editor-tool), command-line interface to edit Mediawiki articles
- [MediaWiki ShortURL Builder](https://github.com/redwerks/mediawiki-shorturl-builder)
- [OmniAuth Mediawiki](https://github.com/timwaters/omniauth-mediawiki), MediaWiki strategy for [OmniAuth](http://omniauth.github.io/omniauth/)
- [Wikimedia::Commoner](https://github.com/jnicho02/wikimedia-commoner), wrapper for the Wikimedia Commons API with additional copyright holder and license details features

### Wikipedia

- [Wikipedia API Client](https://github.com/kenpratt/wikipedia-client)
- [WP2TXT](https://github.com/yohasebe/wp2txt), extract text content and category data from Wikipedia dump files

### Wikidata

- [Wikidatum](https://github.com/connorshea/wikidatum), make requests to the Wikidata/Wikibase REST API
- [gimme_wikidata](https://github.com/bradleymarques/gimme_wikidata), search wikidata
- [WikidataDiffAnalyzer](https://github.com/WikiEducationFoundation/wikidata-diff-analyzer), parse the differences between Wikidata revisions and extract statistics about the changes
- [Wikidata API Client](https://github.com/klacointe/wikidata-client), search for wikidata and wikipedia pages and read their contents
- [Wikidata API Gem](https://github.com/wmde/WikidataApiGem), Extends MediaWiki API Gem with Wikidata-specific features
- [Wikidata for Ruby](https://github.com/wilg/wikidata), includes a command-line interface

### Query about real-world objects

- [WhatIs.this](https://github.com/molybdenum-99/whatis),  a quick probe for the meaning and metadata of concepts through Wikipedia
- [Reality](https://github.com/molybdenum-99/reality), uniform query access to heterogenous web API about real-world knowledge

For new software developed after this post was published, search GitHub for:

[`(mediawiki OR wikipedia OR mediawiki OR wikidata) language:ruby pushed:>2023-12-05`](https://github.com/search?q=(mediawiki%20OR%20wikipedia%20OR%20mediawiki%20OR%20wikidata)%20language%3Aruby%20pushed%3A%3E2023-12-05&type=repositories)